# A series of conjectures on $\sum_{x=0}^{(p-1)/2}(\frac{x^5+cx^3+dx}p)$ (II)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, characters, quadratic-residues

As in [Question 319254](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319254), for an odd prime $p$ and integers $c,d$ we let
$$S_p(c,d):=\sum_{x=0}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac{x^5+cx^3+dx}p\right).$$ If $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then we obviously have
\begin{align}&\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^5+cx^3+dx}p\right)
\\=&\sum_{x=0}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\left(\frac xp\right)+\left(\frac{p-x}p\right)\right)\left(\frac{x^5+cx^3+dx}p\right)=2S_p(c,d).
\end{align}

**Conjecture 1.** Let $p\equiv1\pmod{12}$ be a prime and write $p=a^3+3b^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\equiv1\pmod3$. Suppose that $d\in\mathbb Z$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, then
$$S_p(10d,9d^2)=\begin{cases}-2a&\text{if}\ 3d\ \text{is a quartic residue mod}\ p,\\2a&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

*Remark* 1. In my preperint [arXiv:1812.08080](http://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08080) joint with F. Petrov, D. Krachun vand Vsemirnov, we proved that 
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^5+10x^3y+9xy^2}p\right)=0\tag{$*$}$$
for any prime $p\equiv5\pmod{12}$ and integer $y$.
By Conjecture 2 in [Question 319254](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319254), for any prime $p\equiv1\pmod{12}$ and integer $y$ with $(\frac yp)=-1$, we should also have $(*)$.

**Conjecture 2.** Let $p\equiv1,9\pmod{20}$ be a prime and write $p=a^2+5b^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. If $d$ is an integer with $(\frac d p)\equiv 5^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p$, then 
$S_p(5d,5d^2)=\pm2a$.

*Remark* 2. In the preperint [arXiv:1812.08080](http://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08080), we proved that 
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^5+5x^3y+5xy^2}p\right)=0\tag{$**$}$$
for any prime $p\equiv13,17\pmod{20}$ and integer $y$.
By Conjecture 2 in [Question 319254](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319254), for any prime $p\equiv1,9\pmod{20}$ and integer $y$ with $(\frac yp)\equiv-5^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p$, we should also have $(**)$.

Comment: By Conjecture 1 in Question 319254, for each integer $d$ and any prime $p>3$ with $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ we should have $S_p(10d,9d^2)=0=S_p(5d,5d^2)$.